# geoserver 2.5 403 error

Tags: geoserver, error, boundless-suite

I use a opengeo standard installation of geoserver 2.5 and after adding the roles and users to access a specific store/layer, it so happens that if i'm editing the features as the normal user (has admin permissions on the store), when saving the edit, I get a error 403.

If I do the same, but with the admin user, the changes get saved.

Did I forget to do something in the service/users/roles config of the user?

Answer (score 1):

Well as mentioned here http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/security/services.html , all I had to do, was add my user to the services panel to be able to do wfs.transactions.